# Spring Cloud Stream - Testing consuming from and producing into a shared topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, event-driven

I have been trying to implement the following solution:

[image: spring-cloud-stream-shared-topic]

My application is expecting to consume message `A` from `all-messages`, do some business logic and then producing
message `B` back into `all-messages`.

The reason why I am using `StreamBridge` instead of a `Function<A,B>` is because I want the producing side to work with an arbitrary
number of produced messages, but for the sake of this example I am trying to simplify the scenario to just one.

Additionally, there is a custom router function in order to avoid an infinite loop, that dispatch the incoming messages
into the appropriate consumer, either `incoming` or `discarded`, would be great to have a way to effectively discard messages.

That being said I cannot quite get the implementation right using Spring Cloud Stream.

I'd like your help to understand what am I doing wrong and how to fix the current configure/setup in order to make the solution work as expected, specifically:

- Is this solution supported by Spring cloud stream?
- Is my application configuration correctly implementing the solution diagram above?
- Which bindings exactly should I use inside the app when sending/receiving messages?

The major headache comes from the bindings, so I tried to write a test with different combinations of incoming and outgoing bindings to see what is what, something along these lines:

```java
class ScsProblemTests {

    /* ... */

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("bindings")
    void consumeFromAndProduceIntoSharedTopic(String incomingBinding, String outgoingBinding) {
        givenNoOutgoingMessages();
        whenAnIncomingMessageArrives(incomingBinding);
        thenEventuallyAnOutgoingMessageIsProduced(outgoingBinding);
    }

    public static Stream<Arguments> bindings() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(null, null),
            Arguments.of(null, "outgoing-out-0"),
            Arguments.of(null, "all-messages"),
            Arguments.of("incoming-in-0", null),
            Arguments.of("incoming-in-0", "outgoing-out-0"),
            Arguments.of("incoming-in-0", "all-messages"),
            Arguments.of("all-messages", null),
            Arguments.of("all-messages", "outgoing-out-0"),
            Arguments.of("all-messages", "all-messages")
        );
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

I am running this set of tests with a `overrides` spring profile, where I setup the destination overrides as per the diagram, I am also testing the same set with a different spring profile with no overrides, again just for having a control group to compare with. Only 2 tests from the `no-overrides` profile pass, the rest fails.

The `no-overrides` profile does not match the design obviously, but I was curious to see how the overrides where affecting the results, specifically the `no-overrides` tests that passes are the one where:

- incomingBinding=null, outgoingBinding=null
- incomingBinding=null, outgoingBinding=outgoing-out-0

And for my understanding of Spring Cloud Stream, even in this `no-overrides` case, I'd expect also the following to pass (the are not):

- incomingBinding=incoming-in-0, outgoingBinding=null
- incomingBinding=incoming-in-0, outgoingBinding=outgoing-out-0

At this point I am starting to think I misunderstood some concepts behind Spring Cloud Stream, but I really hope
you can provide some useful advise.

I have shared my code into [this](https://github.com/th3n3rd/scs-problem) repository for convenience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what is your question exactly ? You tried to generally describe the requirements your code is trying to achieve , but what is it exactly you are asking?

Comment: I'd like some help to understand what am I doing wrong and how to fix the current configure/setup in order to make the solution work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here are the problems in my implementation and how to fix them:

1. I had a typo in the routing configuration, so wasn't enabled, this is how to enable the function router in spring cloud:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        routing:
          enabled: true
```

2. Because I have a function router involved, I don't need anymore to configure my `incoming-in-0` binding instead I need to configure a destination for the function router:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: all-messages
        outgoing-out-0:
          destination: all-messages
      source: outgoing
      # ...
```

3. I misunderstood bindings/destinations and how to use the testing helpers provided by the framework, specifically `InputDestination` and `OutputDestination`. I was not sure what parameters should I use to send a message or receive one. The answer is that those components are there to simulate the real binder (e.g. RabbitMQ, Kafka, etc), and they have no knowledge of a `binding` (which is a construct from spring cloud), they only know about `destination`.
   So in my case that translated into something like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
class ScsProblemTests {

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;

    /* ... */

    @Test
    void consumeFromAndProduceIntoSharedTopic() {
        // prepare message A ... 

        // simulate message "A" arriving into "all-messages"
        input.send(messageA, "all-messages")
        
        // ...
        // application will pick up the message
        // the function router will dispatch the message to the right consumer
        // the consumer does some business logic
        // eventually a message "B" should be produced into "all-messages"
        
        // check if "all-messages" contains message "B"
        // NOTE: "all-messages" will contain both "A" and "B"
        var discard = output.receive(1000, "all-messages"); // message A
        var messageB = output.receive(1000, "all-messages");
        // assertions ...
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Note: as per the comments in the pseudo-code, the final state is represented by having both `A` and `B` in `all-messages`, in this case the `OutputDestination` is simply a window to the shared channel, which obviously will also contain the initial message we sent.

Hopefully this makes sense. I cleaned and pushed a working version of the code into a `fixed` branch in the same repository so you can see the actual fixes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are reusing the same queue for different type of messages which forces you to introduce the routing. Further more, the two functions appear to exist in the same runtime space, so why not just `pass-by-reference` (invoke one function from another), why do you need to introduce networking.

I don't know your use case, hence can only comment on what i see, but it appears there is a design issue here. Perhaps if you actually share the use case we can help with the appropriate solution.

Comment: The usa case is: there is a shared event stream (in the diagram "all-messages"). My application is interested in consuming some of those events ("A"), but also want to raise new events ("B", "C", "D", "E") that might be of interest to other applications, hence they produced events need to go back into the shared stream ('all-messages"). Is the solution not matching this use case?